# Is it safe to remove a user in MVLSC?

Tags: volume-license

My old boss at work was in charge of our Microsoft Volume Licensing Service Center for the company. He no longer work with us, and he gave me all the administrative privileges with my own account. Is it safe to delete his account? Or could it affect the ID licenses he previously purchased?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Microsoft's convoluted
[VSLC Administrator FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/administrator-faq).

The main points seem to be:

- You must first assign the Administrator role to your account
- You cannot delete a user, only
  [revoke his permissions to the Licensing ID(s)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/administrator-faq#how-do-i-change-or-adjust-permissions-that-have-already-been-assigned),
  and the user name will remain on your Users list
- To
  [change the contact information on the Enrollment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/administrator-faq#how-can-i-change-contact-information-on-my-enrollment),
  you need to contact your Microsoft Reseller to process the change of contact request
  on your behalf.

All in all, I suggest contacting Microsoft and have them do as much of the work
as they are ready to do.

My own opinion is that if you fully control the old Administrator's account
and he cannot login any more (password change or whatever your organization does),
I'm not sure that this heavy procedure is worth the potential problems.